# Random JavascriptException on parallel run

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

While executing parallel tests in TestNG I randomly got JavascriptException. This occurs on random test. The weird thing is that it goes smoothly on 5 threads, but on 6 threads it always fails one test.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.79)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.79, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Mar\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:62538}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:639)
    at testUtils.SeleniumUtils.moveToElementAndClick(SeleniumUtils.java:53)
    at pageObjects.common.TopBar.addNewNews(TopBar.java:113)
    at news.NewsTestE2E.addNewNews(NewsTestE2E.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB I updated the question with full stacktrace

Comment: @Marcin - The stacktrace doesnt indicate any traces of this being a problem either with TestNG or Selenium for that matter. Can you please edit your question and include a complete sample that can reproduce this issue ?